# Help deciphering abbreviated terms in technical manual

Tags: terminology

I'm having trouble deciphering some abbreviations in a parts list of capacitors from a technical manual for an old (80s-90s) computer.  I've managed to work out that "CPCTR" stands for "Capacitor", however I'm not sure about the abbreviations after that.  I guess they describe the type of capacitor? Here's the different types listed:

- CPCTR CPLT
- CPCTR CER ("Ceramic" maybe?)
- CPCTR TANT
- CPCTR DCPLR ("DC Polarized" maybe?)
- CPCTR ALEC

The one I really need to translate is CPCTR DCPLR.  The others are provided mainly for context.  Google has been no help I'm afraid.

Comment: CPCTR TANT - Tantalum, 
CPCTR ALEC - Aluminium Electrolytic

Comment: Typical values (and voltage ratings) could be a good clue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quite likely: DECOUPLER

[Source](http://chrisacorns.computinghistory.org.uk/docs/Acorn/Manuals/Acorn_A300_SMCLSup.pdf)

*Remove the decoupling capacitor 'A' nearest to 1C1*

Part list:
Item Part No. Description Qty Remarks
92     0680,100 CPCTR DCPLR 33/47n AX 12V 39 'A'

From other part lists, it is said to be a SMD component.

Comment: wow. great detective work

Comment: google is still your friend ;)